# Resetting result of a calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I have a program that calculates a number from the database with the input of the user. I made it work fine, but my problem now is when I reset the page, the result is still there. Even if I use `unset` in the variable of the result, it still stays there. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  include 'dbconnect.php'
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div align="center">
    <form method="POST">
        <?php
            unset($res);
            $fetch = "SELECT Valor FROM taxas WHERE Id = 5";
            $send = mysqli_query($con, $fetch);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($send)) {
                $value = $row['Valor'];
            }
            echo $value;
            if (isset($_POST['op'])) {
                $num1 = $_POST['n1'];
            }
            $res = $value + $num1;
        ?>
        *<input type="text" name="n1"> 
        <button name="op"> = </button>
        <?php
            echo $res;
        ?>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you need, code for the "dbconnect.php":

```
<?php
$place = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$database = "teste2";
$con = mysqli_connect ($place, $user, $pass, $database);
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Error: " . $con->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: you need to redirect to the same page

Comment: @v Sugumar I tried to do that but the page gives an error saying that the page rederect me too many times

Comment: have a reset button <a href='your url'>

Comment: I considered the possibility of a reset button, but I would like without a reset button so when the people make their calculations, leave, and then come back, the result will be still there and it will confuse the user.

Comment: @AndrePrata If you CLOSE the entire browser and then open up the page again, the number shouldn't be there. It is most likely because you are updating the page with the previous POST request. **Please note** that you are echoing the database value right after making the database call

Comment: @Classified Is there a way to clear the post every time I do reload then?

Comment: The browser will always try to use the same POST data as the previous request if available on a reload, which is the intended behavior. Why is it a problem that the data is shown there when you reload? IF you type something different in the input field and press submit it will change the output.

Comment: And if I use the "Get" method? It is a problem because this probably will go to the public and I would like to make the best program possible. I am a trainee and my boss gave me that chalenge.

Comment: GET would result in the exact same result, except for your query parameters will be visible in the URL. You can't really circumvent this behavior in a good way when you 'reload' the page, because it will always contain the previous POST request. What people usually do is something called [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$res = '';
$fetch = "SELECT Valor FROM taxas WHERE Id = 5";
$send = mysqli_query($con, $fetch);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($send)) {
    $value = $row['Valor'];
}
echo $value;
if(isset($_POST['op'])) {
    $num1 = $_POST['n1'];
}
$res = $value + $num1;
```

maybe helps you

Comment: try to restart apache, maybe its a bug

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the request is a POST request and only do the calculations if it is:

```
$res = '';
if (!empty($_POST)) {
   // your calculations
   $fetch = "SELECT Valor FROM taxas WHERE Id = 5";
   $send = mysqli_query($con, $fetch);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($send)) {
       $value = $row['Valor'];
   }
   echo $value;
   if (isset($_POST['op'])) {
       $num1 = $_POST['n1'];
   }
   $res = $value + $num1;
}
```

Comment: With 'reseting' the page, you mean to reload the page?

Comment: No problem ;) Ok, but then the browser should ask something like "do really want to resend the data?"... and that's the reason, why your calculation is still there. It's the same request with the same data as before. But when closing the browser and reopen the same url, you should not see the calculation again. If you still see the calcuation, there might be a wrong setting with the caching of the page or request. So just have a look at the HTTP cache header.

Comment: Thank you, it helped understand the problem